# WEEKDAY Error With Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have dates within a cell using this format: (February 13 2014).

When I try to use "WEEKDAY(C2)" I get #VALUE!

I have no idea how to fix this and I need some help to finish this web scraping project. Any ideas?

Comment: If you're actually doing web-scraping (presumably with a VBA-based solution), why not simply reformat that string in the VBA?

Comment: I'm using Import.io for the scrapping. This is my first go at scrapping so I'm learning lol.

Comment: ok well that makes more sense then. There are at least two good answers for you below. Clarify whether the parentheses are actually part of the cell value?  (If so, both answers probably need to account for that)

Comment: Thanks for helping out. I'm at the hospital right now but once I get home tonight I'll be able to pay with the formulas given and find what works for the data. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the date is a string, and not a real Excel date formatted as you show.  The WEEKDAY function needs have a "real Excel date" as its argument, not a string.

If the apparent spaces between the date components are spaces, then the following formula should work:

```
=WEEKDAY(--SUBSTITUTE(C5," ",", ",2))
```

**EDIT**: As David Zemens just pointed out, the double unary seems to be unnecessary with the weekday function.  So

```
=WEEKDAY(SUBSTITUTE(C5," ",", ",2))
```

should be a better solution.

If they are something else, the formula would be different, but the principal would be similar

Another method: You may be able to convert it to a "real date" by using the Text to columns wizard, but DON't split it on anything. (You can do that by selecting something like TAB as the delimiter; since there are not tabs, no splitting).  When you get to step 3, merely check that it is a date in MDY format.  That wizard is pretty smart.  Then you can use the WEEKDAY function directly.

Comment: I have no idea who downvoted this, but it absolutely works and your explanation is spot on: because OP is missing the comma delimiting *day* and *year*, Excel can't recognize it as a date.

Comment: @DavidZemens Thank you David.  I just noticed that after I added an addendum indicating that the Text-to-Columns wizard could also convert the date.

Comment: Good addendum, too. Some users (I am not one of them) are OK with "helper columns" and otherwise violating the structure of the worksheet, but your first method avoids that mess altogether, and I would find it preferable. :)

Comment: @DavidZemens I agree with you in general.  Except that if he is going to use that date in multiple formulas, it might be better to convert it to a "real date" using TTC on the single column (no helpers required).  The subsequent formulas would be simpler.  The downside would be the extra step of running the wizard, depending on how he is "scraping".

Comment: @pnuts 2010. Same result with/without the `--`.

Comment: @pnuts I'm using Excel 2007, running under Windows 7; but it's also worked on previous versions of Excel and Windows.  If the double unary doesn't work, DATEVALUE should.

Comment: If he's actually doing web-scraping then I would really recommend validating/formatting the data in memory/VBA, rather than on the worksheet. :)

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks for pointing out that the double unary was unnecessary.  I'm so used to using that when converting text strings to dates, that I never thought to try the WEEKDAY function without it.  I will add that to my answer.

Comment: I never knew about the double unary until just now :)

Comment: @DavidZemens If you use it without the weekday function, it will convert the text string to the "date number"  e.g 41683.  It's the same principal as multiply by 1 or adding zero, to convert.

Comment: @pnuts I should also point out that I am using a US version of Excel.  Don't know if that makes a difference.

Comment: Nice answer, I was only two hours too late :). Interestingly, it works for me even if I don't specify the last argument. I can never remember if it's `Substitute`, `Replace`, both or neither that let you specify instance, so that's how I found out.

Comment: This solved the problem easily thank you for helping out :) Time to dig into some data!

Answer (score 1):

One way to do so... maybe not best since it involves adding so many rows

Add a fresh column D and E if not available..

Then use Text to Columns on Column C, with space as delimiter... (This will split column on spaces into 3 columns)

Add a new Column D with formula

```
=MONTH(C3&1)
```

Make sure new Column D is of type General or Number rather than Date

Then you can use the following formula

```
=DATE(F3,D3,E3)
```

Answer (score 1):

Formula only:

```
=WEEKDAY(DATE(RIGHT(C2,4),MONTH(LEFT(C2,FIND(" ",C2)-1)&1),(MID(C2,FIND(" ",C2)+1,2))))
```

with thanks to @tgeery.

Answer (score -2):

Your dates are not in the correct format.

```
WEEKDAY(DATE(2014,2,13))
```

should work because the argument for the weekday function needs to come from the DATE function.

Comment: without explaining how to get from `"February 13 2014"` to the Y-D-M components, this isn't really an answer...  Also, it's not correct that the argument for weekday *needs* to come from the `Date` function. The `Weekday` function takes any serial date.